# Unable to render Mongo Database Documents on Device though working on Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to have the documents \ items on Mongo atlas render on the android screen without any success. The items however are rendering on Postman GUI. Below is the code

```js
useFocusEffect((
 useCallback(
   () = {
     setFocus(false);
     setActive(-1);
     // Products
     axios
       .get(`${baseURL}products`)
       .then((res) = {
         setProducts(res.data);
         setProductsFiltered(res.data);
         setProductsCtg(res.data);
         setInitialState(res.data);
         setLoading(false)
         console.log(res.data);
       })
       .catch((error) = {
         console.log('Api call error')
       })
```

the connection to the DB is ok..
[Database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s42lA.png)

There is no console.log message on displayed on terminal. What could I be missing?

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to consume the response data in an Android app or through a web browser on a mobile device?

Comment: @StephenTaylor I am trying to load the data on my Android device / App.  Expo Go to be specific. Not through a web browser..

Comment: Could you please post your Expo Go code. It seems like your problem resides on the client-side – how you're consuming the data.

Comment: @StephenTaylor Expo Go is just the interface / App where the data should display on my device/phone. When I was working with a flat list it was rendering Ok. When I tried connecting to the Mongo Atas with axios that's when I got into this challenge. However, connection to the DB via postman is Ok.